# Update value to mutiply objects by Transaction in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm writing a simple chat application with Firebase. My Database looks like this[image] like this

Now, I want to increment a variable "counter" (+1) to all objects with one groupId (ex: groupId ="eee1111111111111")

I only know transaction with only one DatabaseReference like as

```
    DatabaseReference mCount = myDataRef.child(Consts.CHILD_RECENT).child("-  
     KUgZ3_5nXUpsyVNTnn5");

    mCount.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
        @Override
        public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
            FRecent f = mutableData.getValue(FRecent.class);
            if (f == null) {
                return Transaction.success(mutableData);
            }
            f.counter = f.counter + 1;
            mutableData.setValue(f);
            return Transaction.success(mutableData);
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b,
                               DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // Transaction completed


        }
    });`
```

Comment: Thanks for edit @Frank van Puffelen , Please help me more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can query all child that have groupId equalTo "eee1111111111111".
Then you loop all this child and update the count number

```
DatabaseReference ref = myDataRef.child(Consts.CHILD_RECENT);
ref.orderByChild("groupId").equalTo("eee1111111111111").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        // loop all result
        for (DataSnapshot child: snapshot.getChildren()) {
            // update count for child: child.getKey()
            DatabaseReference mCount = ref.child(child.getKey());

            // run your transaction here
            mCount.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
                ...
            }
        }
    } 

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks you! I found my solution with your help. Using addListenerForSingleValueEvent insteadt of addValueEventListener ( this make loop forver update counter). Now code my like as:

Comment: @GeoWesley you are right, thank you so much for correct me. I don't test my solution before because i don't have enough enviroment, just give you an idea. Can you help me edit my answer to correct format ˆˆ

Comment: i so new in overstack with 41 replutations ^-^. I can't edit comment. Thanks you again for your helpful. i posted my solution below

Comment: I forget about that :D, I have edit my answer, please check it and it would be great if you can mark it as correct answer ˆˆ

Comment: how to i make it as correct answer? Now i only know vote ^^

Comment: :D below the vote down button, there is a correct button (V), click in it and this answer will mark as correct. happy finding

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Phan van Linh for your help. I found one soulution my issue by your code. And i use addListenerForSingleValueEvent method instead of addValueEventListener method( this make loop forever in update database). Now my code like as:

```
 private void updateRecents(String groupId){

    final DatabaseReference mRecent = myDataRef.child(Consts.CHILD_RECENT);

    mRecent.orderByChild("groupId").equalTo(groupID).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                DatabaseReference  mCount = mRecent.child(child.getKey());
                UpdateCounterWithTransaction(mCount);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });


}
private void UpdateCounterWithTransaction(DatabaseReference _mCount){
    _mCount.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
        @Override
        public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
            FRecent f = mutableData.getValue(FRecent.class);
            if (f == null) {
                return Transaction.success(mutableData);
            }
            f.counter = f.counter + 1;
            mutableData.setValue(f);
            return Transaction.success(mutableData);
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b,
                               DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        }
    });
}
```